# Loading gif for a page with a long cfloop in ColdFusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion page that loops over a (potentially) long query that can have several hundred items to loop over and display.  The first time you visit the page, there can be a 3-10 second delay for the page to load. I'm not having much luck with Google lately, and haven't found a very good tutorial on how to display a loading gif. Can someone help me out please? From what I can tell, ajax is commonly used for this, but *if possible*, I would like to shy away from this and use a jQuery solution. Thanks in advance!

```
<cfdirectory directory="(dir name)" name="dirQuery" type="file" filter="*.pdf" action="list">

...html table start goes here...

<cfloop query="dirQuery">

...items go here...

</cfloop>
```

This will be for internal users only, so it doesn't have to be pretty. I just don't want users getting click-happy when they think the page isn't loading.

Comment: as a side note, you might want to use `cfqueryparam` on your SQL parameters

Comment: edited to implement duncan's suggestion

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to provide the code for this since there are a million and one tutorials out there for using jquery to ajax something in, however as a starter for 6, you'll be wanting to look at the jQuery ajax function:

something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: data.cfm
}).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

more info is available here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You'll want to move the code you already have into a seperate `cfm`, so you'll end up with maybe:

`index.cfm` where the jQuery calling code is and;
`data.cfm` where the current code you have is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<cfdirectory>` to get all the files and folders in one directory, then a query-of-queries to extract just those files that are PDFs, you might be faster using the `filter` attribute on the cfdirectory to only get the PDF files, and avoid having to then do the QoQ.

```
<cfdirectory directory="(dir name)" name="dirQuery" filter="*.pdf" type="file">

<cfloop query="dirQuery">...</cfloop>
```

Comment: I implemented this, and it definitely sped up a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, all you want to do is to send a "loading"  tag down to the browser at then beginning of the request, so the user has something to look at whislt the rest of the request runs and generates the rest of the mark-up?

Are you thinking of like just a "I'm working" spinning ball, or something that shows the actual progress of the slow-to-run code? You aren't very clear on that.

If it's just a "I'm busy" image, then just output the image tag, and flush the buffer:

```
<img src="whatever.gif">
<cfflush>
```

Then that lot will get sent to the browser immediately, whilst the rest of the request continues.

If you want to offer real telemetry of the progress, then you'll need a more complex solution which has the browser poll the server (via AJAX) for some indication of where it's at in the process. I'm sure JQuery etc have a plug-in to do this. Google jquery progress indicator" (something like [this](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)).

CF provides a [`<cfprogressbar>`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfprogressbar) tag, but I'd never advocate using server side code to generate client-side functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I am looking for. Sorry for not being more clear. Specifically, I was wanting just a placeholder image to display like you said. I don't really care how far along the process is.

Comment: I didn't realize this, but apparently the page is inside of a custom wrapper/tag of some sort and CFFlush doesn't work. I'll keep digging around :)Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem with the flush approach :-(

Comment: off-topic, but you have to wonder why Coldfusion has a CFDump and CFFlush but no CFWipe...(the SO mods are gonna have a field day with me)

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to prevent multiple page requests by your click happy users, there are other options available to you.

First, use javascript to hide form submit buttons and or anchor tags once they have made their request.

Second, use cfflush.